# Drupal: how to minimize log menu?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

long time ago I've expanded my Log menu in Drupal. See picture:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/logsMenu.png

Now I don't remember anymore how to change that setting and remove the advanced log items from the menu.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to *Home » Administer » Site building » Menus* (`http://localhost/drupal/6/index.php?q=admin/build/menu`), select the menu containing the entries you want to be removed (probably *Navigation* or *Administer*), and either edit all entries you want to change, or reset the parent menu to defaults.

Comment: thanks for reply, I unchecked and now they are disabled (it is written (disable) near the title. However they are still there! I guess because the administration menu (I'm using it, Iforgot to mention in the question) always display all items.

Comment: I actually remember I activated them with 1 click from another setting page.

Comment: try other menus at Home » Administer » Site building » Menus, there might be duplicates.

Comment: you might also start making notes so you remember better :)

Comment: The menus only organize the way in which the enabled plugins should be displayed. They don't solve the problem at the root. The administration menu bar on the top is not customizable using SIte Building Menus. This was a small change, if I start to make notes of all small changes I get crazy :) THat's why I asked to the community.

Comment: what module are you using for the administration menu bar on the top?

Comment: this should be part of your question ... the administration menu *does* display the menu structure from *Home » Administer » Site building » Menus » Administer* (or ... *Navigation » Administer*) - see http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/contributions/modules/admin_menu/README.txt?revision=1.28&view=co . did you try "Flush all caches" from "Administer >> Site configuration >> Administration menu"? what other settings are there under "Administration menu"?